# The automorphisms of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-extensions

Find the automorphisms of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ field explicitly.

It is well knowned that the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ is not Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ since any automorphism is determined by where it sends $\sqrt[4]{2}$ and of the four possibilities $\{±\sqrt[4]{2},±i\sqrt[4]{2}\}$, only two are elements of the field. And since $\mathbb{Q}(√2)/\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})/\mathbb{Q}(√2)$ are quadratic extension so galois extension. As we know that any extension $K$ of $F$ of degree $2$ is of the form $F(√D)$ where $D$ is the element of $F$ which is not a squre in $F$. Then how can we express $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})/\mathbb{Q}(√2)$ as like $F(√D)$ and what are the automorphisms of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: I cannot make sense of most of what you wrote. In particular, the extension of Q by the fourth root of 2 is certainly not quadratic!

Comment: Is it easier for you to grapple with automorphisms of Galois extensions?  If so, the splitting field for $x^4-2$, which is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i)$ is Galois with $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ as a subfield.  Subfields of Galois extensions have as their automorphisms the automorphisms of the Galois extension itself restricted to the subfield (often this restriction is merely the identity on that subfield).

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez♦. Sorry, instead of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})/\mathbb{Q}(√2)$ will be a quadratic extension. I have edited it.

Comment: Moreover, note that an extension is Galois $\iff$ the number of automorphisms is equal to the degree of the extension. If it's not Galois, then the number of automorphisms divides the degree of the extension, which means there are either $1$ or $2$ automorphisms for this scenario, which should give you some reassurance that your ultimate list is complete. You are certainly on the right track in the very first bit: any automorphism will be determined by its action on $\sqrt[4]{2}$, and this element can go only to one of its $4$ "Galois conjugates".  (P.S. I think you forgot an $i$ in the list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two automorphisms, the identity, and the automorphism mapping
$2^{1/4}$ to $-2^{1/4}$. It's not a Galois extension, so doesn't
have four automorphisms. The only conjugates of $2^{1/4}$ in $\Bbb Q(2^{1/4})$ are $\pm 2^{1/4}$.

Comment: Thanks for your nice representation. But last one question I want to know that ... How can I express $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})/\mathbb{Q}(√2)$ as like $F(√D)$ that I have already mentioned in the question...?

Comment: @abcdmath take $D=\sqrt2$.